# How to verify message is delivered or not in AWS SNS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is my lambda function. only return message-id and request-id. but how to verify the message is delivered or not?

```
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
           AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: 'xxxx',
                secretAccessKey: 'xxxx',
                region: 'xxxx'

            });
            const mobile = 'xxxxxxx';
            const sns = new AWS.SNS();
        const confirmUpload =  (callback) => {
          sns.publish({
            Message: 'Test From Admin side',
                Subject: 'Admin',
                MessageStructure: 'string',
                PhoneNumber: mobile
          }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) callback(false, err);
            else callback(true, result);

          });
        };
        exports.handler =  (event,context, callback) => {
            confirmUpload((st, data) =>{
                if(st){
                    let record = {
                        "data": JSON.stringify(data),
                        "event": event,
                        "context": context
                    };
                    callback(null, (record));
                } else{
                    callback(data, "not send");
                }
            });
        };
```

And here is the response when running the lambda function

```
        "{\"ResponseMetadata\":{\"RequestId\":\"e8a07b26-d793-58e1-a529-2d7ac17aca9x\"},\"MessageId\":\"b8ecbcac-9f83-5bca-a9eb-eaf0896a69b\"}",
```

Comment: Please help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 6):

If you enable the [delivery status feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html) on your topics you can use the message ID field in order to track the delivery status of the messages you have published.

> After you configure the message delivery status attributes, log
>   entries will be sent to CloudWatch Logs for messages sent to a topic
>   subscribed to an Amazon SNS endpoint. Logging message delivery status
>   helps provide better operational insight, such as the following:
>
> - Knowing whether a message was delivered to the Amazon SNS endpoint.
> - Identifying the response sent from the Amazon SNS endpoint to Amazon SNS.
> - Determining the message dwell time (the time between the publish timestamp and just before handing off to an Amazon SNS endpoint).

[Configuring Delivery Status Logging Using the AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html)

You can look into this article to look for delivery status using message ID

[using-the-delivery-status-feature-of-amazon-sns](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-delivery-status-feature-of-amazon-sns/)

Btw I will not suggest to check in the same lambda but to configure cloud watch logs and filter failure topic only. Here will be flow

1. Enable delivery status logs for the topic
2. Configure filter on Cloud watch for the failed topic
3. Trigger lambda when delivery status if failed
4. Process the failed SNS topic in lambda.

You may also like [SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/) for SNS by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable SNS dead-letter queues to catch messages that can’t be delivered to subscribers:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/designing-durable-serverless-apps-with-dlqs-for-amazon-sns-amazon-sqs-aws-lambda/